# who to change text after a specific sentance

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu, scripting

hi i get this file /lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service
i when to change something in this line

> ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd_conf/blablabla/vsftpd.conf

i want to replace after vsftpd_conf/ with a variable ! i tested this

```
domaine=2m-partners.tn

 d=$(echo "${domaine}" | sed -e 's/[]$.*[\^]/\\&/g' )

 sed -e "s/^vsftpd_conf\.*$/vsftpd_conf\/${d}\/vsftpd.conf/g" /lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service
```

but a get at result this

> ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf/${d}/vsftpd.conf

Comment: This is not possible. The regular expression in your question matches "vsftpd_conf" at the beginning of the line and followed by any number of dots until the end of the line. The ExecStart line is not a match. This should work: `sed "s|^ExecStart\(.*vsftpd_conf/\)|ExecStart\1$d|"`.

Comment: it dosen't work ! :/

Comment: domaine=mail.2m-partners.tn
d=$(echo "${domaine}" | sed -e 's/[]$.*[\^]/\\&/g' )
sed -i "s|^ExcStart\(.*vsftpd_conf/\)|ExecStart\1$d|" /usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service don't work for me

Comment: You are right, it results in an error message. But this is not the command that I gave you. I just tested my command, and the result is `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd_conf/mail.2m-partners.tnblablabla/vsftpd.conf`.

Comment: there is another solution can help me ? please

Comment: I gave you a solution. Why do you need another one?

Comment: sed -i "s|^ExcStart(.*vsftpd_conf/)|ExecStart\1$d| this one ??? it dosen't work for me

Comment: Well, as I said, I did not give you this command. It doesn't have backslashes, and it misspells "Exec". Just try the one I gave you: `sed "s|^ExecStart\(.*vsftpd_conf/\)|ExecStart\1$d|"`.

Comment: but i need to replace blablabla/vsftpd.conf withc /mail.2m-partners.tn/vsftpd.conf this results ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd_conf/mail.2m-partners.tnblablabla/vsftpd.conf is not the solution

Comment: Then you have to set `d` to `mail.2m-partners.tn`. Right now it is set to something else. And you have to include blablabla in the regular expression. I suggest you edit the question and state clearly what the expected outcome of your command is.

Comment: You can use your original attempt, but (1) leave out the `^` and (2) the backslash before the dot: `sed -e "s/vsftpd_conf.*$/` and so on. The `^` anchors your string to a line start, while `\.` matches a regular dot instead of any character. @berndbausch adds some more optimization, but those need explanation. Your attempt works with those two modifications

Comment: @phillippos how can i change it ?

Comment: By deleting those two characters in your script.

Comment: \.  and ^ ?? @philippos ?

Comment: The `^` and the backslash before the dot (not the dot itself). So your regexp remains `/vsftpd_conf.*$/`, like written above

Comment: when i put this sed -i 's/vsftpd_conf.*$/\$domaine/vsftpd.conf/' /lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service it get error (sed: -e expression #1, char 29: unknown option to `s')

Comment: Because you forgot to escape the slash in the path (you did that correctly in your question)

Comment: okey i tested  sed -i 's/vsftpd_conf.*$/\$domaine/vsftpd.conf/' /lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service but i get $domaine with no variable in ! i got /etc/vsftpd_conf/$domaine/vsftpd.conf